# Question about the premium from selling bonds

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, treasury

Suppose I bought a $1000 ten-year treasury note (2031) with 4% yield. After one year, the yield decreased to 1%. If I sell it, how much premium will I get? Will I get (3% * 1000)? If the calculation is more complicated, how much approximately will the premium be (between $10-$50 or $50-$100 or $100-$500 or ...)?

Comment: What is the coupon rate?